# How to increase size of the "content" property in css

Tags: css

I have added one icon in my webpage using `content` property.

```
content: "\11";
```

But its looking very small I need to increase the size of this icon.I tried with `background-size`  propery and `width` and `height`property.
But No changes in the size of icon.
How to increase it?

Comment: Increase the `font-size`.

Comment: Here you need to you use font-size.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope this will help you:

```
font-size:40px;
```

Answer (score 1):

With content other than actual font, you'll need to bump up the px value by a couple of 10's to see an actual change in size.